# How to differentiate between multiple colliders on the same GameObject in Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've read a lot about colliders in Unity2D and it seems that there is no way of differentiating between multiple colliders if they are on the same gameObject. Forms of this questions have already been asked quite a few times, it seems like most people suggest having different sorts of colliders, as in box, circle... but this won't work for my use case.

Do I have to make gameObjects for each of the colliders and tag them? Isn't there another way to do this? Has Unity updated their way of doing this? Does somebody know of a plugin maybe that could be used for this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure where the use case for multiple colliders on the same object derives from, but you can either **a)** have one collider as a collider and a second collider as a trigger (different methods are called (OnCollisionEnter / OnTriggerEnter)) ... or **b)** you can use empty gameObjects nested with additional colliders.

Comment: Think it is actually an optimization feature that all colldiers are summed up and threated as a single one. Would indeed be nice to have the possibility to avoid that. On the other hand that would also mean to change the interface of the OnCollision.. functions to provide arrays of everything and that again would result in constant allocations and de-allocations. Because what if multiple colliders are hit at once?

Yeah, nested GameObjects (without separate rigid bodies) are the intended way to go.

Comment: By the way, a plugin for that would be quite simple. Give all the nested objects a script which catches the collisions and calls a method in the parent's script's.

Comment: @RobertFrench The issue here is that all of the colliders are triggers in my case...

Comment: @AlexGeorg How can this be the intended way to go? That sounds horrible, doesn't it? Might be I'm just not used to this but to me it seems like really bad design.
Ad plugin - But you don't happen to know of one, do you?

Comment: @KonstiLackner Still unclear on the "why" for multiple triggers/colliders, what are you trying to accomplish? There may be other options.

Comment: @KonstiLackner Why exactly does it sound horrible? Are you worried about your software architecture becoming more complicated through this, or are you concerned about performance?